# What caused the deaths of the Prince's parents in Beauty and the Beast (2017)?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In both Disney versions of *Beauty and the Beast*, the Prince is an orphan when he is cursed.  In the 2017 film,

> his parents died in two separate events.

However, in both the 1994 cartoon and 2017 live action remake, it isn't outright explained how they perished.  Given

> The Prince's father lived long enough to raise him to inadequate adulthood

one would assume that the potential causes could be different.

Were there any easily-missed clues or writer/director commentary as to their causes of death?

Comment: Whoa...started to close a dupe of the other question...fortunately spotted the difference at the last minute and managed to undo everything.

Comment: @Paulie_D SFF loves parallel questions. Just this time I made two for myself.

Comment: ["There's a real-life story behind all those absent parents"](http://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/entertainment/news/a38594/reason-disney-characters-orphans-parents-die/)

Answer (score 1):

### The Queen.

Prince Adam's mother died of a *[vague unnamed wasting illness](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IncurableCoughOfDeath)*, possibly [tuberculosis](https://www.britannica.com/science/tuberculosis/Tuberculosis-through-history), but equally likely to have also any one of a number of other conditions such as cancer and heart failure.

> And then the boy’s mother, the Beast’s mother, Belle clarified in her head, had grown ill. Belle’s eyes grew wide as Mrs. Potts explained that the boy had stayed by his mother’s bedside day and night, watching as she withered away. He had begged the doctors to help her but they just shook their heads and offered up false promises.
>
> <sub><sup>[Beauty and the Beast: Official Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30145679-beauty-and-the-beast-novelization)</sup></sub>

---

### The King.

The fate of Prince Adam's father is unclear. At the time of his cursing, Adam is the Prince-in-residence of the castle and his father is absent from the ball. No mention is made of a brother or anyone else who stands to inherit the throne. On balance, it seems likely that **his father is still alive and merely living elsewhere** or *otherwise the commoners would recognise the Prince as their new king as soon as memories of his existence resurfaced*.

> Now, with every moment that passed, they were beginning to remember all they had forgotten: the castle with the cruel king and the haughty prince, the lavish parties that had once been thrown, their loved ones who had worked there.